# Changing the value of a Number Bug AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, numbers, flash-cs6

Hey everyone so I am having some trouble here. Been at it for an hour now and can't find a solution.

So I Have a movie clip named `_Bunny` added to the stage like so:

```
        _Bunny = new mcBunny;
        stage.addChild(_Bunny);
        _Bunny.x = (stage.stageWidth / 2) - 225;
        _Bunny.y = (stage.stageHeight / 2) - 330;
```

Now what this _Bunny does is move across the stage horizontally from right to left in a loop which i have set up like so in a Enter_Frame event listener:

```
private function bunnyView():void 
    {
        _Bunny.x += nBunnySpeed;

        if (_Bunny.x >=(stage.stageWidth / 2) + 215)
        {
            _Bunny.gotoAndStop("leftView");
            nBunnySpeed--;

        }
        if (_Bunny.x <=(stage.stageWidth / 2) - 215)
        {
            _Bunny.gotoAndStop("rightView");
            nBunnySpeed++;
        }


    }
```

It's speed is the `nBunnySpeed` which is equal to 5. Now I have another function that I am trying to change the value of the `nBunnySpeed` to say 20 whenever the `nScore` is equal to 1 like so:

```
private function updateDifficulty():void 
    {
        if (nScore >= 1)
        {
            //Increase Speed

            nBunnySpeed = 20;


        }
```

but the bug that in which is produces is the Bunny shooting off to the right side of the screen which is the "+x" no matter what I do this always happens.

Can anyone see what I might be doing wrong? I don't understand why this is happening. Please help!

Comment: your post says "nScore is equal to 1" but code is `nScore >= 1` - check if one is not correct.

Comment: You should check if your `updateDifficulty()` isn't called once per frame. If it is, make it not, because if it is, your `nBunnySpeed` is set to 20 every frame regardless of your speed altering code.

Comment: @Vesper Yeah I had the UpdateDifficulty() function called inside the Enter_Frame game loop. But since I removed it what would I do with it now? How would I change the Number if it's not being checked?

Comment: Yeah still can"t get it to work. It just acts crazy whenever i try to change the nBunnySpeed to a different number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need some kind of a flag that indicates that the difficulty has been already updated. Then, when you call `updateDifficulty` it first checks if there's a real need to update speed now, if there's none, it just returns. If yes, however, then you update your bunny's speed and set that flag so that the next time the function will not alter the bunny's speed.

```
var diffUpdated:Boolean=false;
private function updateDifficulty():void 
{
    if (diffUpdated) return; // here
    if (nScore >= 1)
    {
        //Increase Speed
        if (nBunnySpeed<0) nBunnySpeed=-20;
          else nBunnySpeed = 20; // retain the direction of bunny's movement
    }
    diffUpdated=true;
}
```

Now, whenever you want your difficulty to be updated, you do `diffUpdated=false;` and voila, bunny's speed will be updated by this. For this, however, you will need more than two levels of speed, maybe one for 10 score, one for 50 and one for say 200.

Comment: Awesome! As always you have helped me figure this out! I couldn't thank you enough. DO you know what I can do to keep the bunny on the stage? If I update the speed to say 50? When I tried a high number like that it seems to ease off the screen real fast then comes back and eases off the screen for the other side and repeats. I think it has something to do with the bunnyView() function and the way i initiate the speed like so nBunnySpeed++ and --; But not too sure how to go about fixing it. I tried but cant get it working. Any ideas why its happening?

Comment: NeverMind figured it out using max's method below thanks vesper man. Hey do you still have that tower defense website? I still want to promote your website. I already released my first app and this second app will be out by Monday. Email me if you can NathanFitchett@Gmail.com

Answer (score 1):

What you do in this function

```
private function bunnyView():void 
{
    _Bunny.x += nBunnySpeed;

    if (_Bunny.x >=(stage.stageWidth / 2) + 215)
    {
        _Bunny.gotoAndStop("leftView");
        nBunnySpeed--;

    }
    if (_Bunny.x <=(stage.stageWidth / 2) - 215)
    {
        _Bunny.gotoAndStop("rightView");
        nBunnySpeed++;
    }
}
```

is check whether the _Bunny is offscreen or not. And if so, the nBunnySpeed will be nBunnySpeed - 1. But since BunnySpeed = 20, it will be 20 + 19 + 18 + 17, still going right. If you'd to turn it to BunnySpeed = -BunnySpeed, it will reverse immediately and go back.

Comment: That function works fine on changing the position of the bunny. It goes back and fourth appropriately. It's just whenever I change the nBunnySpeed value to a higher integer like 20 thats when it fly's off the screen in the positive x direction.